# How to check if a Gun unordered list is empty?

Tags: gun

Given the following, how would one go about determining if the machines list is empty in order to add a machine?

```js
let gun = new Gun();
let machines = gun.get('machines');
```

How do I check if the machines list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

This from Mark Nadal:

```js
// machineId and location defined elsewhere

machines.val(table => {
  if (Gun.obj.empty(table, '_') {
  // table is empty so we can add something to it
  let machine = gun.get('machine/' + machineId);
  machine.put({machineId, location}};
  machines.set(machine);
  } else {
  // table is not empty
})
```

- table is a data node that has all the row pointers in it (not the actual sub-objects)
- so if table has 0 items on it, then it is empty! Or if table is null or undefined
- HOWEVER, gun has its {_: {...}} meta data it includes on every node, so you need to ignore that.
- Gun.obj.empty({}) tests if an object is empty (you can use lodash or something else), the second parameter tells it to IGNORE a key, like in this case '_'. So it will still say that yes it is empty if it has 0 properties other than the metadata property.